# Text won't stay with image slider when page is resized

Tags: html, css, carousel

I've got a pure CSS image slider and a block of text plus footer etc. underneath it. When the page is resized, the image slider resizes neatly and everything underneath it resizes, but the image slider pulls away from the block of text and everything while the block of text and everything else stays put. I've tried messing with the positioning of both the image slider and the section but everything ends up breaking the image slider or causing overlap. What am I doing wrong/how can I get this to work so that when the browser resizes and the slider gets smaller, the block of text and everything else beneath it stays stuck to the bottom of the slider and the whole page shrinks vertically to match how the slider shrinks vertically when resized? Please ignore any funny-looking buttons/links or whatever as I'm only including the code that is for the image slider and the rest of the text so as not to clutter up my included fiddle with code that doesn't need fixing. I know not to include static URLS inside the page but images won't load in the fiddle if I don't specify their exact locations.

If you want to see the test page running live, it's at [Rack Inspections test page](https://cafenocturne.com/RackInspections/index.html).

```css
:root {
    --ORANGE: #FA6114;
    --BLUE: #0000FF;
    --GREY: #787878;
}

/* apply a natural box layout model to all elements */
*, *:before, *:after {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 100vw;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

html {
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    max-width: 100vw;
}

body {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -moz-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
    color: var(--GREY);
}

.orange {
    color: var(--ORANGE);
}

.blue {
    color: var(--BLUE);
}

.grey {
    color: var(--GREY);
}

.wrapper {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}

header {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100vw;
}

nav {
    max-width: 100vw;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    outline: none;
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-family: 'Century Gothic', Arial, 'Arial Unicode MS', Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    margin-right: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
    top: 15px;
}

nav a, nav a:link, nav a:visited, nav a:hover {
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--GREY);
}

nav a:active {
    color: var(--ORANGE);
}

nav a:hover {
    color: var(--BLUE);
}

ul#nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 19px;
}

section {
    max-width: 100vw;
    background: WHITE;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    position: relative;
    cursor: default;
}

.SecTitle {
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.LinkCurrent {
    color: var(--ORANGE);
    cursor: default;
}

.logo {  
    position: relative;
    top: 15px;
    left: 30px;
    max-width: 100vw;
    height: auto;
}

article {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;

}

.services {
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.PHSRLink {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 25px 0 25px;
}

.inspectionsLink {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 25px 0 25px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.PHSRTitle {
    font-family: Century Gothic, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

footer {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    color: var(--GREY);
    font-family: Century Gothic, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 100px 20px 20px 0;
}

footer a:link {
    color: var(--ORANGE);
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    text-decoration: none;
}

footer a:visited {
    color: var(--ORANGE);
    text-decoration: underline;
}

footer a:hover {
    color: var(--BLUE);
    text-decoration: underline;
}

/* Image Slider */
#slider {
    max-width: 100vw;
    width: 952px;
    height: 409px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 23px;
    margin-bottom: 45px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #FFF;
}

#slider > div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    animation: slide 20s infinite;
    opacity: 0;
}

#slider > div:nth-child(2) {
    animation-delay: 5s;
}

#slider > div:nth-child(3) {
    animation-delay: 10s;
}

#slider > div:nth-child(4) {
    animation-delay: 15s;
}

#slider > div:nth-child(5) {
    animation-delay: 20s;
}

@keyframes slide {
    10% {
        opacity: 1;
        }
    20% {
        opacity: 1;
        }
    30% {
        opacity: 1;
        }
    40% {
        opacity: 0;
        }
}
```

```html
        <div id="wrapper">
            <header>
                <img class="logo" src="http://www.cafenocturne.com/RackInspections/images/logo.png" alt="Rack Inspections - Click to return to main page">
            <nav>
                    <ul id="nav">
                        <li class="LinkCurrent">HOME</li>
                        <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT US</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </nav>
            </header>

            <section>
                <div id="slider">
                    <div style="background-image:url('http://www.cafenocturne.com/RackInspections/images/slide1.png')"></div>
                    <div style="background-image:url('http://www.cafenocturne.com/RackInspections/images/slide2.png')"></div>
                    <div style="background-image:url('http://www.cafenocturne.com/RackInspections/images/slide3.png')"></div>
                    <div style="background-image:url('http://www.cafenocturne.com/RackInspections/images/slide4.png')"></div>
                </div>

                <article>
                    Rack Inspections process gives our clients a greater understanding of rack storage systems, best practices and safety awareness to ensure that your company is in compliance with all safety regulations. In addition, we provide straight forward racking inspections with detailed recommendations.<br>
                </article>

                <div class="services">
                    <div class="PHSRLink">
                        <div class="SecTitle orange">PHSR</div>
                        <img width="268" height="133" alt="Pre-Start Health and Safety Review image" src="http://www.cafenocturne.com/RackInspections/images/MainImage-1-GUY.png"><br><br>
                        PHSR (Pre-Start Health &amp; Safety Review)?<br>
                        We can help.<br><br>
                        <a href="PHSR.html" class="button" title="Click here to read more about PHSR">READ MORE</a><br><br>
                    </div>

                    <div class="inspectionsLink">
                        <div class="SecTitle orange">Inspections</div>
                        <img width="268" height="133" alt="Inspections image" src="http://www.cafenocturne.com/RackInspections/images/MainImage-2-Wrench.png"><br><br>
                        Rack inspections identify safety concerns<br>
                        and deficiencies with rack storage systems.<br><br>
                        <a href="inspections.html" class="button" title="Read more about our inspection process">READ MORE</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>

            <footer>
                <a href="mailto:info@rackinspections.ca" title="Click here to send us an email."><span class="orange">info<span class="blue">@rackinspections</span>.ca</span></a><br>
                Copyright <script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear())</script><br>
                All Rights Reserved.<br>
                <span style="font-size: 10px;">Designed by RackInspections.ca</span>
            </footer>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) and specifically `contain`, the replaced content is scaled as large as possible maintaining its aspect ratio while fitting within the element’s content box. Because of this, a situation called [letterboxing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letterboxing_(filming)) occurs, and this is a perfect example of that. The `#slider` has an initial height of 409px and although that "fits" nicely for larger viewports, for smaller viewports the images in the slider aren't occupying 100% of the 409px explicit height causing a bunch of whitespace between the images and the `<article>` text.

If you instead use `background-size: cover` on the `#slider > div` elements then the replaced content is sized to maintain its aspect ratio while filling the element’s entire content box. Now the text will always live right underneath the image slider for all viewport widths. To make the `#slider` height more responsive (ie not always 409px), you could swap the absolute unit value with a relative length unit like `vh` so its height is dynamically calculated by the browser.

```css
:root {
    --ORANGE: #FA6114;
    --BLUE: #0000FF;
    --GREY: #787878;
}

/* apply a natural box layout model to all elements */
*, *:before, *:after {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 100vw;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

html {
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    max-width: 100vw;
}

body {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -moz-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
    color: var(--GREY);
}

.orange {
    color: var(--ORANGE);
}

.blue {
    color: var(--BLUE);
}

.grey {
    color: var(--GREY);
}

.wrapper {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}

header {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100vw;
}

nav {
    max-width: 100vw;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    outline: none;
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-family: 'Century Gothic', Arial, 'Arial Unicode MS', Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    margin-right: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
    top: 15px;
}

nav a, nav a:link, nav a:visited, nav a:hover {
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--GREY);
}

nav a:active {
    color: var(--ORANGE);
}

nav a:hover {
    color: var(--BLUE);
}

ul#nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 19px;
}

section {
    max-width: 100vw;
    background: WHITE;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    position: relative;
    cursor: default;
}

.SecTitle {
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.LinkCurrent {
    color: var(--ORANGE);
    cursor: default;
}

.logo {  
    position: relative;
    top: 15px;
    left: 30px;
    max-width: 100vw;
    height: auto;
}

article {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;

}

.services {
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.PHSRLink {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 25px 0 25px;
}

.inspectionsLink {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 25px 0 25px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.PHSRTitle {
    font-family: Century Gothic, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

footer {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    color: var(--GREY);
    font-family: Century Gothic, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 100px 20px 20px 0;
}

footer a:link {
    color: var(--ORANGE);
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    text-decoration: none;
}

footer a:visited {
    color: var(--ORANGE);
    text-decoration: underline;
}

footer a:hover {
    color: var(--BLUE);
    text-decoration: underline;
}

/* Image Slider */
#slider {
    --h: 60;
    max-width: 100vw;
    width: 952px;
    height: 45vh; /* Vary this */
    height: calc(var(--h) * 1vmin); /* responsive unit */
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 23px;
    margin-bottom: 45px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #FFF;
}

#slider > div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    animation: slide 20s infinite;
    opacity: 0;
}

#slider > div:nth-child(2) {
    animation-delay: 5s;
}

#slider > div:nth-child(3) {
    animation-delay: 10s;
}

#slider > div:nth-child(4) {
    animation-delay: 15s;
}

#slider > div:nth-child(5) {
    animation-delay: 20s;
}

@keyframes slide {
    10% {
        opacity: 1;
        }
    20% {
        opacity: 1;
        }
    30% {
        opacity: 1;
        }
    40% {
        opacity: 0;
        }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
            <header>
                <img class="logo" src="http://www.cafenocturne.com/RackInspections/images/logo.png" alt="Rack Inspections - Click to return to main page">
            <nav>
                    <ul id="nav">
                        <li class="LinkCurrent">HOME</li>
                        <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT US</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </nav>
            </header>

            <section>
                <div id="slider">
                    <div style="background-image:url('http://www.cafenocturne.com/RackInspections/images/slide1.png')"></div>
                    <div style="background-image:url('http://www.cafenocturne.com/RackInspections/images/slide2.png')"></div>
                    <div style="background-image:url('http://www.cafenocturne.com/RackInspections/images/slide3.png')"></div>
                    <div style="background-image:url('http://www.cafenocturne.com/RackInspections/images/slide4.png')"></div>
                </div>

                <article>
                    Rack Inspections process gives our clients a greater understanding of rack storage systems, best practices and safety awareness to ensure that your company is in compliance with all safety regulations. In addition, we provide straight forward racking inspections with detailed recommendations.<br>
                </article>

                <div class="services">
                    <div class="PHSRLink">
                        <div class="SecTitle orange">PHSR</div>
                        <img width="268" height="133" alt="Pre-Start Health and Safety Review image" src="http://www.cafenocturne.com/RackInspections/images/MainImage-1-GUY.png"><br><br>
                        PHSR (Pre-Start Health &amp; Safety Review)?<br>
                        We can help.<br><br>
                        <a href="PHSR.html" class="button" title="Click here to read more about PHSR">READ MORE</a><br><br>
                    </div>

                    <div class="inspectionsLink">
                        <div class="SecTitle orange">Inspections</div>
                        <img width="268" height="133" alt="Inspections image" src="http://www.cafenocturne.com/RackInspections/images/MainImage-2-Wrench.png"><br><br>
                        Rack inspections identify safety concerns<br>
                        and deficiencies with rack storage systems.<br><br>
                        <a href="inspections.html" class="button" title="Read more about our inspection process">READ MORE</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>

            <footer>
                <a href="mailto:info@rackinspections.ca" title="Click here to send us an email."><span class="orange">info<span class="blue">@rackinspections</span>.ca</span></a><br>
                Copyright <script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear())</script><br>
                All Rights Reserved.<br>
                <span style="font-size: 10px;">Designed by RackInspections.ca</span>
            </footer>
        </div>
```

Comment: But then the slider doesn't resize with the page, and I need it to resize with the page.

Comment: That's why I recommended you replace your absolute unit length height of 452px with something more responsive. I used `height: 45vh` in my demo above and that resizes the `#slider` height dynamically with the viewport height.  Or you could use `rem` etc and/or introduce some media queries if you don't want to use other relative length units.

Comment: Vary the browser window height and you'll see the image slider height is responsive and being calculated based on the viewport height when using `vh`. If you want to mimic the same behavior as `contain`, I created a "responsive unit" and it scales with the viewport using `vmin` and css variables.

Comment: That's fantastic! Thank you! Setting the height to a vh was just the trick!

Comment: Actually, I noticed a problem. The slider only begins to resize when the window has been resized to hide half of the image. It doesn't resize instantly. What could that be?

Try it on my test page to see what I mean.
https://www.cafenocturne.com/RackInspections/index.html

Comment: Its not a problem, just means you have some fine tuning to do to find the "sweet spot" height value, as its now filling the entire content-box with `background-size: cover`. The height is being calculated by the size of the viewport window. So whenever you vary the viewport height the height of the `#slider` is recalculated when using `vh`. If your instead using the responsive unit that I made with `calc()`, then that is using `vmin` (1% of the viewport's smaller dimension) which means height is recalculated everytime the viewports smaller dimension is varied.

Comment: Nope. I used your entire code and changing the vh doesn't change when the image begins to resize. I tried 5vh and 100vh and no difference. Check my live test page. It uses exactly your code as you gave it.

Comment: I just checked your live page, it looks fine and the height of the image is responsive when the viewport width gets smaller. Do you understand that unless you change the viewport height, then `height: 45vh` or any `vh` usage won't change the image height? If you use `vw` then the image will be sized based on the viewport width. Using the responsive unit calculation with `calc()` and css variables instead of the `vh` usage in my answer mimics the behavior of `contain` which it seems like your wanting to obtain.

Comment: And look closely at the code you copied :) your not even using the `vh` on the live site, its the `height: calc(var(--h) * 1vmin);`. Therefore, vary the `--h: 60` value if you want it to change height sooner/later ie increase or decrease the responsive unit `--h` if your going to use `calc()`. Otherwise comment that out and go for a `vh` or `vw` value. Note: that responsive unit usage I added as an extra option for you in my answer if you didn't want to use `vh`, `vw` or another relative length unit.

Comment: Even if you use `vh` or the responsive unit, the same behavior will happen as `cover` is being used to ensure the image fills the entire content-box. You have to account for this with media queries or a "desirable" value unless you want to use `contain` and suffer from the "letterboxing".